# how to create a new dictionary in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In python 3.5.1

```
og_dict = {'name':'user1', 'salary':'1k'}
og_dict_list =[]
for i in range(2,5):
    og_dict['salary'] = str(i)+'k'
    og_dict_list.append(og_dict)
for og_dict_obj in og_dict_list:
    print(og_dict_obj)
```

Above code produces following output :

```
{'name': 'user1', 'salary': '4k'}
{'name': 'user1', 'salary': '4k'}
{'name': 'user1', 'salary': '4k'}
```

But I am expecting below output :

```
{'name': 'user1', 'salary': '2k'}
{'name': 'user1', 'salary': '3k'}
{'name': 'user1', 'salary': '4k'}
```

Apparantely python modifies the existing dictionary only and does not create a new one. What can I do to solve this issue?

Is there exist a way to create a new dictionary object from existing one?
Is there any other collection which is more suitable for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has been pointed out, it doesn't matter what you do, when in the loop you have:

```
for ob_dict_obj in ob_dict_list:
    print(ob_dict)    # wrong!
```

it always print the value for `ob_dict` and doesn't matter what values you put in `ob_dict_list`.

---

This said the problem is that you are *modifying* the **only** dictionary. You want to create a new one for each iteration:

```
og_dict = {'name':'user1', 'salary':'1k'}
og_dict_list =[]
for i in range(2,5):
    new = og_dict.copy()
    new['salary'] = str(i)+'k'
    og_dict_list.append(new)
for og_dict_obj in og_dict_list:
    print(og_dict_obj)
```

There is a number of ways to copy a dictionary, like just doing `dict(of_dict)` instead of calling `.copy()`. However, AFAIK, there is no single method that allows you to copy & update a dictionary at the same time.

However there isn't much point in having the `og_dict` outside the loop at this point:

```
og_dict_list =[]
for i in range(2,5):
    og_dict = {'name':'user1', 'salary':str(i) +'k'}
    og_dict_list.append(og_dict)
for og_dict_obj in og_dict_list:
    print(og_dict_obj)
```

---

To answer your broader question: the kind of behaviour you are looking for is typical of functional languages which have persistent data structures. However in imperative languages having an operation that copies & updates would be a simple way to shoot yourself on the foot by creating tons of unwanted copies.

*All* built-in cointainers act the same as `dict`: update methods simply modify the current object and you have to explicitly copy the object to avoid the side effects.

Comment: Also, you should be printing `og_dict_obj`, not `og_dict`

Comment: @PrashantSethi Oh yeah. I copy&pasted from the OP. Added a note about that too (even though I hope it was simply a typo in the OP code when he wrote it here).

Comment: Yeah  og_dict instead of og_dict_obj was a typo. Thanks for the answer.
I can not use the second solution for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

```
og_dict_list =[]
for i in range(2,5):
    og_dict = {'name':'user1', 'salary':str(i) +'k'}
    og_dict_list.append(og_dict)

for og_dict_obj in og_dict_list:
    print(og_dict_obj)`enter code here
```

There is always a better way to do this. You can also use the update() method in Python to add new items to dictionaries.